# ViewController's background color can not be changed in the viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibackgroundcolor

I'm trying to change `UIViewController`'s `backgroundColor`. 
I wrote the code in the `viewDidLoad` method. My other objects are shown on the screen without any problem but `backgroundColor` `property` did not work. The screen is `gray`. I also tried `[UIColor redColor]` or to write only this row in the `viewDidAppear` method but nothing changed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15
                                                green:0.15
                                                 blue:0.3
                                                alpha:1.0];       
    //Add start button
    [self.view addSubview:[self createButton:@"ButtonSample.png"
                               setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                             buttonPositionX:(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-30)
                             buttonPositionY:(CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)+30.0)
                                 buttonWidth:80.0
                                buttonHeight:20.0]];

    //Add game title label
    [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:@"Vecihi"
                              labelFontName:@"Chalkduster"
                              labelFontSize:20
                             labelPositionX:CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-25
                             labelPositionY:CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)
                                 labelWidth:80
                                labelHeight:20
                                  fontColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]];

    //Add game logo imageView
    [self.view addSubview:[self createImage:@"Spaceship"
                             imagePositionX:CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-30
                             imagePositionY:CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-80
                                 imageWidth:40
                                imageHeight:60]];
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you set background color somewhere else. Try to search `backgroundColor` string in view controllers file.

Comment: there is nowhere else I set background colour

Comment: are you sure there's no other view other than self.view for this view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it an it works just fine to set the color of a view controller's content view in viewDidLoad.

In my case, I had a view inside the content view that took up most of the visible area, so very little of my custom color was visible. I had to set the background color of my subview to clear before I could see the changed background color.

Is it possible that you have a subview that completely fills your content view and hiding it's background color?

If that's not the case, try adding a breakpoint to your viewDidLoad method to make sure it's being called.

Comment: viewDidLoad is being called, no problem with that. I set up a label, imageview and a button in that method. I think you right it is possible one of my subviews fill the background. I have three subviews as I said UILabel, UIButton, UIIMageView. I tried it without calling these 3 subviews to understand which one cause it, I left only setbackgroundcolor in the viewDİdLoad but nothing changed.